# One Google cloud server can't access bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

On the Google cloud platform I have set up a bucket to store some files.
I have recreated a compute engine with the scope "read/write" on Storage as the default scope does not give access to the buckets.

Yet, when I try to gsutil cp on the compute engine I get "insufficient privileges".

Where should I start to debug this? I can't seem to find any log files or similar on the Google Cloud platform... "gcloud init" is authenticated to the service account.

If I create a new engine from scratch it works fine but I need to keep the server. The compute engine is in the Asia zone, not sure if that matters.

The user manual says that changing the scope should be enough. The service account is a member of the project editors so it should have permisson given the scope is fine...

thanks..

Comment: I solved it myself... a "gcloud components update" did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself... a "gcloud components update" did the trick..